# Replace tinyMCE content with original text

Tags: javascript, c#, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE to change the content as I wish. But when I save the content, the result comes with HTML tags. Like

```
<p>int a,b,c;</p> <p>c=a+b;</p>
```

Original text was

```
int a,b,c;

c=a+b;
```

This is my view

**Create.cshtml :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // Initialize your tinyMCE Editor with your preferred options
        tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "modern",
            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing: true,

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            content_css: "css/example.css"
        });
    </script>

</head>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>tblStackoverFlow</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeSnippet)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CodeSnippet)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeSnippet)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tags)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tags)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tags)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Index.cshtml :**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodeSnippet)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tags)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id })            
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Here, I want to replace the content for `item.CodeSnippet` field.

C# Code

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var questions = db.tblStudent.ToList();
            return View(questions);
        }
```

I have tried to repopulate the original text using `.replace` function

```
replace(/<p>/g, "\n").replace(/<\/p>/g, "");
```

But it is not working. 
Help me.

Comment: what is the data type of `CodeSnippet`?

Comment: @Abdur, it is nvarchar(max).

Comment: Ok and your model is tblStuden, I guess. To show it in view page you can try the last method described in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One Solution : In Controller where u r processing the value**

```
string x = "<p>a+b=c</p>";
x = x.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>","").Replace("<P>","").Replace("</P>","");
```

**SO:**

```
string yourString = "<p>int a,b,c;</p><p> c + a = b;</p>";
yourString = yourString.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>","").Replace("<P>","").Replace("</P>","");
```

**Output will be:**

```
yourstring = "int a,b,c; c+a=b;";
```

**Lets Try this way:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var questions = db.tblStudent.ToList();
        // Iterate through each item of the table
        foreach(var tmp in questions)
        {
            tmp.CodeSnippet = tmp.CodeSnippet.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>","").Replace("<P>","").Replace("</P>","");
        }
        return View(questions);
    }
```

**If you want to add a line break after each semicolon, then:**

```
tmp.CodeSnippet = tmp.CodeSnippet.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>","").Replace("<P>","").Replace("</P>","").Replace(";",";\n");
```

**Update 1:**

```
private string StripHTML(string source)
{
    try
    {
        string result;

        // Remove HTML Development formatting
        // Replace line breaks with space
        // because browsers inserts space
        result = source.Replace("\r", " ");
        // Replace line breaks with space
        // because browsers inserts space
        result = result.Replace("\n", " ");
        // Remove step-formatting
        result = result.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
        // Remove repeating spaces because browsers ignore them
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                                                              @"( )+", " ");

        // Remove the header (prepare first by clearing attributes)
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*head([^>])*>","<head>",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"(<( )*(/)( )*head( )*>)","</head>",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 "(<head>).*(</head>)",string.Empty,
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // remove all scripts (prepare first by clearing attributes)
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*script([^>])*>","<script>",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"(<( )*(/)( )*script( )*>)","</script>",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
        //         @"(<script>)([^(<script>\.</script>)])*(</script>)",
        //         string.Empty,
        //         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"(<script>).*(</script>)",string.Empty,
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // remove all styles (prepare first by clearing attributes)
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*style([^>])*>","<style>",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"(<( )*(/)( )*style( )*>)","</style>",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 "(<style>).*(</style>)",string.Empty,
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // insert tabs in spaces of <td> tags
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*td([^>])*>","\t",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // insert line breaks in places of <BR> and <LI> tags
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*br( )*>","\r",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*li( )*>","\r",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // insert line paragraphs (double line breaks) in place
        // if <P>, <DIV> and <TR> tags
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*div([^>])*>","\r\r",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*tr([^>])*>","\r\r",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<( )*p([^>])*>","\r\r",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Remove remaining tags like <a>, links, images,
        // comments etc - anything that's enclosed inside < >
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"<[^>]*>",string.Empty,
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // replace special characters:
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @" "," ",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&bull;"," * ",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&lsaquo;","<",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&rsaquo;",">",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&trade;","(tm)",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&frasl;","/",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&lt;","<",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&gt;",">",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&copy;","(c)",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&reg;","(r)",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Remove all others. More can be added, see
        // http://hotwired.lycos.com/webmonkey/reference/special_characters/
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 @"&(.{2,6});", string.Empty,
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // for testing
        //System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
        //       this.txtRegex.Text,string.Empty,
        //       System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // make line breaking consistent
        result = result.Replace("\n", "\r");

        // Remove extra line breaks and tabs:
        // replace over 2 breaks with 2 and over 4 tabs with 4.
        // Prepare first to remove any whitespaces in between
        // the escaped characters and remove redundant tabs in between line breaks
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 "(\r)( )+(\r)","\r\r",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 "(\t)( )+(\t)","\t\t",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 "(\t)( )+(\r)","\t\r",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 "(\r)( )+(\t)","\r\t",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Remove redundant tabs
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 "(\r)(\t)+(\r)","\r\r",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Remove multiple tabs following a line break with just one tab
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                 "(\r)(\t)+","\r\t",
                 System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Initial replacement target string for line breaks
        string breaks = "\r\r\r";
        // Initial replacement target string for tabs
        string tabs = "\t\t\t\t\t";
        for (int index=0; index<result.Length; index++)
        {
            result = result.Replace(breaks, "\r\r");
            result = result.Replace(tabs, "\t\t\t\t");
            breaks = breaks + "\r";
            tabs = tabs + "\t";
        }

        // That's it.
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
        return source;
    }
}
```

**You can add this method, this has taken care of almost all html tags, then just do as below.**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var questions = db.tblStudent.ToList();
        // Iterate through each item of the table
        foreach(var tmp in questions)
        {
            tmp.CodeSnippet = StripHTML(tmp.CodeSnippet);
        }
        return View(questions);
    }
```

[Source To conver Html to Plain text](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11902/Convert-HTML-to-Plain-Text)

Comment: Getting this error.                                                                                           'system.collections.generic.List<>' does not contain a definition for 'CodeSnippet' and no extension method 'CodeSnippet' accepting a first argument of type

'system.collections.generic.List<>' Could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: my mistake. get the latest `ActionResult Index() method`

Comment: It's working. But, When I get different tags like <pre>, &nbsp..etc.  How to replace ?. Should I replace all of them like  Replace("&nbsp;", " ")

Comment: Check the Update1. Here is a method which can replace almost all html tags, If any tags are not there, you can add here Or you can build one like this as your own requirement.